# Capture Stream Output to String

Tags: c#, .net

I'm calling a library method that writes to a stream. But I want to write to a string. Is this possible? (I do not control the source code of the method I'm calling and so changing that is not an option.)

Experimenting, I tried something like this:

```
iCalendarSerializer serializer = new iCalendarSerializer();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(new iCalendar(), stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
byte[] buff = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(buff, 0, (int)stream.Length);
```

But I get an error on the last line that's something about not being able to access a closed stream. Apparently, the Serialize() method closes the stream when it's done.

Are there other options?

Comment: Side note - you may update your question's title to talk about getting data from disposed MemoryStream as your sample does not even try to get string out of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToArray is one of 2 correct way of getting the data out of memory stream (the other one is GetBuffer and Length). It looks like you just want byte array sized to data of the stream and ToArray does exactly that.

Note that it is by design safe to call these 3 methods on disposed stream, so you can safely wrap `using(stream)` around the code that write some data to the stream.

In you case stream look to be disposed by serialization code (`.Serialize`).

```
iCalendarSerializer serializer = new iCalendarSerializer();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using(stream)
{
  serializer.Serialize(new iCalendar(), stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
byte[] buff = stream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `byte[] buff = stream.ToArray()`?

Comment: Haven't yet converted it to a string (which is what I ultimately need) but, yes, I was surprised to find this does *not* cause the error. How does this work if the stream is, in fact, closed?

Comment: I would just call (assuming ASCII encoding) `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff);`.  My guess is because `ToArray()` is not a method of `Stream`, and therefore does not have to follow the rules defined by extending it.  Plus, you gotta be able to get to that array of bytes somehow.

Comment: MemoryStream has an internal buffer inside. Though stream is closed, internal array buffer is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you need to change the position of the stream before read takes place:

```
stream.Position = 0;
stream.Read(buff, 0, (int)stream.Length);
```

In order to write stream to string you can use StreamReader.ReadToEnd() method:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: That's not it. I believe the second argument specifies that reading should begin from the start. Either way, changing the position does not alter the fact that the stream has been closed. This code produces the same error.

Comment: Second parameter specifies the offset in array buffer. I was sure it will work, let me check.

Comment: I agree. I haven't considered the fact that stream had been closed